# JAVA SQL command not properly ended

Tags: java, oracle

I have this code:

```
buy.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent)
    {
        int r;
        r = table.getSelectedRow();
        String num = (String) table.getValueAt(r, 0);//numele jucariei
        //String cop = (String) table.getValueAt(r, 3);//nr de bucati

        try
        {
            pq = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT *" + "FROM buyid_view");
            xv = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT toyid, copies " + "FROM alldatas_view" + "WHERE toyname ='"+num+"'");
            int buyid = pq.getInt("buyid");
            int toyid = xv.getInt("toyid");
            int copies = xv.getInt("copies");
            copies = copies-1;
            CallableStatement cstmt = con.prepareCall("INSERT INTO buy (buyid, toyid)" + "VALUES (?,?)");
            cstmt.setInt("buyid", buyid);
            cstmt.setInt("toyid", toyid);
            ResultSet rs = cstmt.executeQuery();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You brought a toy.");

            for(int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++)
                for(int j = 0; j < table.getColumnCount(); j++)
                    table.setValueAt("", i, j);

            try
            {
                rs = stmt.executeQuery("UPDATE toys set copies "+ copies +"WHERE toyid= '"+toyid+"'");
            }
            catch (SQLException e)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
            }

            int i = 0;

            try
            {
                rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT *"+
                        "FROM availablebooks_view");
            }
            catch (SQLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally
            {
                try {
                    if(rs.next())
                    {
                        table.setValueAt(rs.getString(1), i, 0);
                        table.setValueAt(rs.getString(2), i, 1);
                        table.setValueAt(rs.getString(3), i, 2);
                        i++;
                        while(rs.next())
                        {
                            table.setValueAt(rs.getString(1), i, 0);
                            table.setValueAt(rs.getString(2), i, 1);
                            table.setValueAt(rs.getString(3), i, 2);
                            i++;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            if(e.getMessage().contains("You have to pay!"))
                warning(frame, "You didn't pay all your products");
            else
                warning(frame, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
});
```

When I compile my program I don't have any error but when I run it and I click on the buy button it gives me an error saying "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended".

Comment: Which SQL statement needs to be "properly ended"? Please edit your question and remove all other code (especially the Java part, because this is an Oracle error message not a Java error) so that only the SQL code remains that results in the error.

Comment: Hint: `UPDATE toys set copies ...` is wrong because it's missing an equals sign (and it's prone to SQL injection and it's hard to read etc...)

Comment: consider `_view" + "WH`

Answer (score 5):

When building SQL statements from strings you must ensure there are spaces where spaces are needed.

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT *"+
     "FROM availablebooks_view");
```

The statement you are sending is

```
SELECT *FROM availablebooks_view
```

which is invalid syntax.  You have this problem in several places in your code.

However, you have a larger issue which results from building your SQL statements piecemeal. This leaves you open to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and you should rewrite your code to use prepared statements and parameters instead.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple errors in your code

First one is

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT *"+
 "FROM availablebooks_view");
```

There is no space between `*` and `FROM`, this will actually creates a syntax error

Second one is

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery("UPDATE toys set copies "+ copies +"WHERE toyid= '"+toyid+"'");
```

There is no `=` after `set copies`, this will also create error.

Third one is

```
CallableStatement cstmt = con.prepareCall("INSERT INTO buy (buyid, toyid)" + "VALUES (?,?)");
```

Give space before `VALUES`